# Redirect to DisplayForm after Item has been saved using CSR and TypeScript

Tags: client-side-rendering, redirect, display-form, newform, typescript

I have a problem that's really bugging me. I am trying to redirect the user to the DisplayForm once he has created a new ListItem in NewForm. I have two problems:

1. I don't know how to get the ID of the newly created item AFTER the
   Save action has been completed (I only find examples using
   PreSaveAction, but the ID is not yet available here)
2. I am using
   TypeScript and can't seem to find the definitions for the functions
   found in various articles on the web.

So has anybody done this before? Or can it even be done?